# Is it possible to manually add an entry to RPM Database?

Tags: rpm

Our current AV install package on Linux(CentOS) servers is in the form of tar.gz and the installation is initiated by execution of the default install.sh script. But since install is not via RPM or YUM, package is not added to the RPM DB and thus, is not picked up in the list of installed software by either our VA scanner or the Asset management software.

While still keeping installation in the same format, what are our options? Is there a way to make sure this gets added to the install packages list on the servers? I checked the RPM DB files under /var/lib/rpm which have " Berkeley DB" format, so wasn't sure how safe is to edit them directly.

We'll be going with RPM install eventually, but for the time being, was wondering if there is any way out. Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

~ Abhi

Comment: Instead of messing up with your system, and potentially corrupting the rpm database, why not building an rpm, and installing from it?

Answer (score 2):

Not really, you are better off packaging the installer in an rpm and installing it through the package manager. 
Messing with rpmdb is not a good idea

BONUS: If you don't want to meddle with rpmbuild, have a look at FPM:

https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

It is a powerful tool that can make or convert packages on the fly